# <function command at 0x7f5e402b46a8> string displaying in help command - py-cord

Tags: python, pycord

Ok, so I'm working with `py-cord` and am having this annoying issue with my help command. I've attatched a screenshot displaying the issue.

Basically there is a string displaying that shouldn't be and I'm trying to figure out what is causing it to display. Does anybody know what is causing it as I have no idea where to even begin on this.

I'm aware of a lack of research displayed, but that is due entirely to the fact that I literally have no idea where to even begin trying to figure this one out. It's the first time I've ever seen this happen with python discord bots so I'm completely stumped.

Any tips or pointers to help me figure this one out would be much appreciated.

The string in mention is: `<function command at 0x7f5e402b46a8>`.

### Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

### Code

Here is my code:
`bot.py`

```py
import discord
import os
import sys
import time
import asyncio
import logging

from config import EMBED_THUMBNAIL, PREFIX, TOKEN, TWITCH, BLUE, GITHUB_REPO, CLIENT_VERSION
from discord.ext import commands

from typing import List

activity = discord.Streaming(name='with cogs | {}help'.format(PREFIX), url='https://twitch.tv/{}'.format(TWITCH))

client = commands.Bot(
    command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or('{}'.format(PREFIX)),
    description='Multi-purpose discord bot built in discord.py\n\n**Version**: {}\n**Repo**: [Socket-Development/Socket-Discord-Bot]({})'.format(CLIENT_VERSION, GITHUB_REPO),
    activity=activity,
    status=discord.Status.online
)

  
class Help(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

class CustomHelp(commands.MinimalHelpCommand):
    async def send_pages(self):
        destination = self.get_destination()
        embed = discord.Embed(color=BLUE, description='{}'.format(commands.command))
        embed.set_thumbnail(url='{}'.format(EMBED_THUMBNAIL))
        for page in self.paginator.pages:
            embed.description += page
            await destination.send(embed=embed)

client.help_command = CustomHelp()

for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        client.load_extension('cogs.{}'.format(filename[:-3]))
        print('Loaded cogs.{}'.format(filename[:-3]))
    else:
        print('Unable to load cogs.{}'.format(filename[:-3]))
                
debug_logger = logging.getLogger('discord')
debug_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
debug_handler = logging.FileHandler(filename='debug.log', encoding='utf-8', mode='w')
debug_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(name)s: %(message)s'))
debug_logger.addHandler(debug_handler)
        
client.run('{}'.format(TOKEN))
```

`config.py`

```py
# Imports
import discord
import os

from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
# Env Variables
TOKEN = os.getenv('CLIENT_TOKEN')
PREFIX = os.getenv("CLIENT_PREFIX")
GIPHY_API = os.getenv("GIPHY_TOKEN")
TENOR_API = os.getenv('TENOR_TOKEN')
TWITCH = os.getenv('TWITCH_CHANNEL')
OWNER_ID = os.getenv('OWNER_ID')
OWNER_NAME = os.getenv('OWNER_NAME')
DEV_TEAM = os.getenv('DEVELOPMENT_TEAM_NAME')
DEV_ID = os.getenv('DEV_ID')
DEV_NAME = os.getenv('DEV_NAME')
GITHUB_REPO = os.getenv('GITHUB_REPO')
EMBED_THUMBNAIL = os.getenv('EMBED_THUMBNAIL_URL')
EMBED_IMAGE = os.getenv('EMBED_IMAGE_URL')
CLIENT_VERSION = os.getenv('VERSION')

# Color Variables
RANDOM = discord.Color.random()
BLUE = discord.Color.blue()
BLURPLE = discord.Color.blurple()
GOLD = discord.Color.gold()
RED = discord.Color.red()
GREEN = discord.Color.green()
DARKRED = discord.Color.dark_red()
DARKBLUE = discord.Color.dark_blue()
DARKGOLD = discord.Color.dark_gold()
```

`requirements.txt`

```css
py-cord
aiohttp
async-timeout
asyncio
asynctest
Babel
decorator
discord
prettytable
requests
setuptools
TenGiphPy
typing
typing-extensions
python-dotenv
```

I'm running off of `Python 3.6.8` and am using the `py-cord` library.

Comment: What is the type of `PREFIX`. Can this issue be caused by `command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or('{}'.format(PREFIX))`? Which actually print some object as this!

Comment: hmmmm... that might be possible. let me see if changeing that fixes it. My PREFIX variable is defined as `s!` in my `.env` file

Comment: you might be able to define `__repr__` or `__str__` methods on your class it looks to me like that is the repr of something ... looks like its not the class from the screenshot... but thats one possibility (not super likely but maybe worth a shot)

Comment: ok so i changed it to `command_prefix=('{}'.format(PREFIX)),` but it still displays that odd string. hmmm okay I'll try that. How would I add that.

Comment: Seems to be coming from `embed = discord.Embed(color=BLUE, description='{}'.format(commands.command))` in `CustomHelp.send_pages`.  `'{}'.format(commands.command)` would give you that exact string

Comment: hmmm... I wonder if it's a bug with `py-cord`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps, try changing

```py
class CustomHelp(commands.MinimalHelpCommand):
    async def send_pages(self):
        ...
    embed = discord.Embed(color=BLUE, description='{}'.format(commands.command))
    ...
```

to

```py
class CustomHelp(commands.MinimalHelpCommand):
    async def send_pages(self):
        ...
    embed = discord.Embed(color=BLUE, description='')
    ...
```

Comment: @JoshuaLewis - yw